# Easy way to list contents of a configured Oracle table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access form that uses a main table (tab1), and uses another table (tab2) as foreign key. Both tables are Oracle tables.

The tab2 table has 3 colums. The form uses 2 columns (id and name) of tab2 for a combo list in the gui.

I would like to list all tab2 values (select * from tab2) in a vba macro. Is there some magical syntax to do that? Something like:

```
With [tab2].Recordset
    While Not .EOF

        For j = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
            debug.print .item(j).name & " : " & .item(j)
        Next

        .MoveNext
        debug.print

    Wend
End With
```

If not, what is the easiest way to do that? tab2 is used by the form (via foreign key), and tab2 is configured as a table in the left panel of access ("tables" section), so I guess there should be an easy way to access the contents of tab2 from vba.

---

**Edit**: Finally found a way to do it:

```
Dim query As String
query = "select * from tab2"

Dim db As ADODB.Connection
Set db = CurrentProject.Connection      ' <<< the key point

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open query, db

With rs
    While Not .EOF

        For j = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
            debug.print .Fields(j).name & " : " & .Fields(j)
        Next

        .MoveNext
        debug.print

    Wend
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

It is a bit long, and has got no magic. But it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `j` to reference a member field of the recordset's `.Fields` collection.  Each field has both `.Name` and `.Value` properties.

So perhaps you need only change the `Debug.Print` line to this ...

```vb
Debug.Print .Fields(j).Name & " : " & .Fields(j).Value
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot it was ".Fields(j)" instead of ".item(j)". Anyway, my question was more centered in the line "With [tab2].Recordset": I was looking for a easy way to refer to the contents of a table that is already configured in Access. Finally I found a way to do it (see the "Edit:" section in my original question). It is not maginal syntax, but it works.